# remove mentions in twitter api callback

Tags: json, api, twitter, callback

i am using this json script to fetch my latest tweet. but i want it to remove the tweets when i "@reply" to someone.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/myusername.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1&include_entities=false">
</script>
```

i went after the "include_entities" but that didn't work. [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) is some more info for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach will be to retrieve the timeline and remove any tweets where:
- The "in_reply_to_status_id" contains a non-blank or non-zero value AND
- The "id" tag in the "user" section is your user id.

Comment: how do i remove the tweets in the timeline?

Comment: I would probably load the timeline XML into an XML object, find the nodes in question via XPATH, and delete them.  How you accomplish this will depend on what platform you're using (.NET, Java, etc.).